# How can I define the return type for a React Router v6 loader?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm using loaders with the new `react-router-dom` and when I use the `useLoaderData` hook in the component, the response type is unknown, so I can't use it. I don't want to use the `as` type definition as I feel like that's kind of cheating but if that's the only way, then, please let me know:

My loader function:

```
{
      path: "/reset-password/:resetToken",
      element: <ResetPassword />,
      loader: async ({ params }) => {
        if (!params.resetToken){
          return null
        }
        const fakeTokens = ["abcdef123456", "bingbong", "foobar"]

        // make API call to check if the given token is valid
        const fakeAPICall = (resetToken: string) : Promise<object> => {
          if (fakeTokens.includes(resetToken)){
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve({ success: true }))
          }

          return new Promise(resolve => resolve({ success: false }))
        }
        
        const resp = await fakeAPICall(params.resetToken);

        return resp;
        
      }
},
```

Inside the `<ResetPassword />`:

```
// this type is "unknown", so I can't access the properties on it
const resetTokenResponse = useLoaderData()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useLoaderData` hook's return type ***is*** `unknown`, so you'll need to re-type it in the component.

See [source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L746-L762)

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the loader data for the nearest ancestor Route loader
>  */
> export function useLoaderData(): unknown {
>   let state = useDataRouterState(DataRouterStateHook.UseLoaderData);
>
>   let route = React.useContext(RouteContext);
>   invariant(route, `useLoaderData must be used inside a RouteContext`);
>
>   let thisRoute = route.matches[route.matches.length - 1];
>   invariant(
>     thisRoute.route.id,
>     `useLoaderData can only be used on routes that contain a unique "id"`
>   );
>
>   return state.loaderData[thisRoute.route.id];
> }
> ```

AFAIK using the `as` typing is how you'd do it, i.e.

```
interface ResetTokenResponse {
  success: boolean;
}
```

...

```
const resetTokenResponse = useLoaderData() as ResetTokenResponse;
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-define-the-return-type-for-a-react-router-v6-loader]

Answer (score 5):

I personally preferred to wrap the original `useLoaderData` in another function (at least while it doesn't support generics):

```
export function useDataFromLoader<LoaderFn extends LoaderFunction>(loaderFn: LoaderFn) {
  return useLoaderData() as Awaited<ReturnType<typeof loaderFn>>
}
```

This new function takes the loader function you wrote to resolve its return type.

Then, instead of using the original `useLoaderData`, we can use the `useDataFromLoader` (or whatever you call it) and pass your loader fn to it (so it can figure out its return type):

```
async function loader() {
  const data = await Promise.resolve({ foo: 'bar' })
  return data
} satisfies LoaderFunction

function Component() {
  const { foo } = useDataFromLoader(loader)
  return <p>foo === 'bar': {foo === 'bar'}</p>
}
```

And I also like to say that my loaders `satisfies` the original/expected `LoaderFunction`, so that we have access to `params` and `request` (for example) and to avoid any type mismatches when using it in the router.